# Compile error at upload or verify in arduino ide

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

this error just appears from nowhere: `program storage space` please help.[image]

Comment: I don’t see the word error anywhere on your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any error uploading, `Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space` tells u your program takes up 1% of the available storage space thats all.
For further info visit [link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/343/why-do-sketches-take-up-so-much-space-and-memory)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. This is just an information on how much memory our sketch uses and how much is available.